# How to optimize simulation time in Simulink

Tags: matlab, automation, simulation, simulink

I am working on my simulation model in Simulink, where I am using "NN Predictive controller" module. I am trying to display the output of the NN Controller in Scope 2.

As you can see in the picture I have 2 signals from workspace. Both are discrete signals (sampling frequency 360 Hz) - both are vectors of 3600 rows.

In NN Predictive controller I have trained neural network to signals of the same size and set the sampling interval to 0.1.

When I run this simulation it runs approximately for 10 hours. Is there any way to minimize the simulation time without increasing the sampling interval in NN Controller? My second question: Why it takes so long?

If you need additional inforation about this model please let me know.

Thank you

Picture:
[image: Simulink simulation model]

Comment: Show you setting at `Simulation / Configuration Parametrs / Solver`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Accelerator Mode` or `Rapid Accelerator Mode` in SL. You can switch the mode in the drop-down list where currently `normal` is selected.

In the `Accelerator Mode` part of the Modell is compiled. In the  `Rapid Accelerator Mode` additionally all scopes are deactivated. For data evaluation you than need to store to the workspace and/or file and analyse it later.

See: http://de.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/how-the-acceleration-modes-work.html

and: http://de.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/improving-simulation-performance-in-simulink.html

Comment: I have installed compiler and successfully used Acceleration mode one time. Once it was actually accelerated, but second time it is slower as ever. I can not use Rapid Accelerator because of this error: directive: Simulink Coder Fatal in block: "EKGNOVE/NN Predictive Controller/S-Function", block type "S-Function": MFile S-functions without a corresponding TLC file are not supported.